# Assigning a dynamic id to a radio button in a loop in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<%1.upto(5) do |n|%>
<label class="label_radio" for="radio-0<%= n %>"><%= n.to_s %>
<%= radio_button_tag 'rating[attesa]', n, false, :class => "cuore_1 ratings_cuore", :id => "radio-N" %>
</label></p>
<%end%>
```

What i want to do is to dinamically assign an id to my radio buttons, so that i have my id like radio-1, radio-2, radio-3 and so on. I'm sure this one's easy :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just interpolate the id in your `:id` field like this:

`:id => "radio-#{n}"`

where `n` is your variable which holds the id